# set default input value symfony 3

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to set a default value in an input. The value is sent from the Controller to the Twig as shown below

ClienteController.php

```
   $loc_default = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Localidad')->findOneBy(
            array('nombre' => 'aaaa'));
       $localidad_default = $loc_default;

    return $this->render('cliente/new.html.twig', array(
            'localidad_default' => $localidad_default,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'form2' => $form2->createView(),
        ));
```

and this is my Twig View with the javascript line

```
  $("#appbundle_cliente_localidad").val({{localidad_default['localidad_default']}});
```

but it shows the following error

**Impossible to access a key "localidad_default" on an object of class "AppBundle\Entity\Localidad" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface.**

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I think you're getting the error because you're attempting to access the 'localidad_default' value as an array: localidad_default['localidad_default']

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$loc_default = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Localidad')->findOneBy(array(
    'nombre' => 'aaaa')
);
$localidad_default = $loc_default->getSomething();

return $this->render('cliente/new.html.twig', array(
     'localidad_default' => $localidad_default,
     'form' => $form->createView(),
     'form2' => $form2->createView(),
));
```

And in the template:

```
$("#appbundle_cliente_localidad").val({{ localidad_default }});
```

**Change getSomething() to a valid public method of your Localidad entity!**

Or if you need the whole entity in your twig template:

```
$loc_default = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Localidad')->findOneBy(array(
    'nombre' => 'aaaa')
);

return $this->render('cliente/new.html.twig', array(
     'localidad_default' => $loc_default,
     'form' => $form->createView(),
     'form2' => $form2->createView(),
));
```

And in the template:

```
$("#appbundle_cliente_localidad").val({{ localidad_default.something }});
```

Comment: I tried, but the error still shows.. Also, I tried alert(localidad_default) but it seems that it doesn't even reaches the twig view

Comment: okay saw that $loc_default is an entity. I updated the answer

Comment: I appreciate your help, but now I get the error Impossible to access a key ("localidad_default.nombre") on a string variable ("aaaa").

Comment: so localidad_default is a string and not an object

Comment: Yes, it's a string populated with the value "aaaa" from the database. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is too much code, if the controller sends the default data from the same action the form is sended just set the value at form or controller like this:

> Inside the form

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name',TextType::class,[
            'attr'=>[
                'value' => 'some_default_value'
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

> Inside the controller

```
...
$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\SomeFormType', $data);
$form->get('somefield')->setData('default_data');
...
```

This way is better for you, less code and test. Also if you need to access database or something it is easier.

Hope it helps!